# Why sometimes Vector3.Distance is not accurate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delay, instantiation

So I have this code:

```
 using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class CreateTrail : MonoBehaviour {
        Vector3 lastLocation;
        int traveled;
        public GameObject obj;
        Quaternion lastQuaternion;
        bool on;
        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
            lastLocation = transform.position;
            lastQuaternion = transform.rotation;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
            if (on)
            {
                if (Vector3.Distance(lastLocation, transform.position) > .1)
                {
                    Instantiate(obj, lastLocation, lastQuaternion);
                    lastLocation = transform.position;
                    lastQuaternion = transform.rotation;
                }
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                if (on)
                {

                    on = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    lastLocation = transform.position;
                    lastQuaternion = transform.rotation;
                    on = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It creates a trail of objects behind the object it is attached to, but often has the object with the script and the object created inside each other. Is there a way to delay or queue up the object instantiation to when the objects are not inside each other, without interrupting the rest of the script? Thanks!

Comment: Feels like this question is not complete. Which part of the code is detecting the bounding box and where do you want that delay to happen?

Comment: @Programmer Currently, I have no Idea how to do so, so it is not in there right now. Ideally, the instantiation would be cued up to be made into effect when the object exits its bounding box, so to not interrupt the rest of the code.

Comment: Your code seems fine except for `.1` which should be `.1f`. But you can try `Coroutine`, `Invoke` or `InvokeRepeating` for the delay. And a **trigger collider** as the bounding box with its `OnTriggerExit` or `OnTriggerExit2D` methods implemented.

Comment: @Bijan Thanks, I think what I may go for is to disable the object on instantiation, then re enable it OnTriggerExit. Is that possible? I have some things pointing towards objects not being able to reactivate themselves.

Comment: Yes you can. Please try these first, then submit a **new question** if you ran into a problem.

Comment: @Bijan thanks, got it to work. Do you think you could put your original question as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @JakeFaulkner TY glad to help:) I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `Coroutine`, `Invoke` or `InvokeRepeating` to create a delay. (**Avoid** using `Timer` and `Thread` as much as you can.)

Then add a **[collider as trigger](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/colliders-triggers)** as a bounding box with its `OnTriggerExit` or `OnTriggerExit2D` methods implemented in order to find out when **another collider** is moved outside the bounding box.

---

However, there may be another issue:

`Vector3.Distance` returns a `float`, and when compared to a `double` (`.1`) one of them should be cast to the type of the other.

It is the `float` which will be implicitly converted to `double` and will have its accuracy changed.

You can avoid this by comparing two `float`s

```
if (Vector3.Distance(lastLocation, transform.position) > .1f)
```

You can find out more about implicit castings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)